# Python lambda returns true even with a false condition

Tags: python, lambda

```
>>> if lambda x: True == True:
... print('yes')
...
yes
>>> if lambda x: False == True:
... print('yes')
...
yes
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to use lamda in a way so it evaluates the

Comment: @ApoorvMishra The lambda should be *called*. And you probably don't `x` in there.

Comment: Why not add to question? Your question has no question at all!

Comment: `foo = lambda x: False == True; print(foo("bar"))  # False`

Comment: Learn more about lambda functions : http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling your lambda as I've explained in my comment, but if you want it inline you can test as:

```
if (lambda x: True == True)(None):
    print("yes")  # prints

if (lambda x: False == True)(None):
    print("yes")  # doesn't print
```

Or more general, since you're not actually using any arguments in your lambdas:

```
if (lambda: True == True)():
    print("yes")  # prints

if (lambda: False == True)():
    print("yes")  # doesn't print
```

Comment: zwer solution serves my purpose! and bruno desthuilliers covers the concept of lambda expresion for me

Comment: Note that the use of a lambda here (defined and called in the same expression) is still a useless waste of both CPU and programmer time (in other words a complete WTF) - you'd get the very same result replacing the lambdas with their bodies, ie `if (True == True)` and `if (True == False):`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - That definitely. Offsetting an expression to call an expression enclosed in a lambda function is an exercise in pointlessness.

Answer (score 2):

The check in the `lambda` is *irrelevant*. What is happening is this:

```
>>bool(lambda x: <anything>)  # 1
True
```

---

<sup>*1. As long as no `SyntaxError` is raised of course.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is parsed the same as

```
if (lambda x: (True == True)):
    print('yes')
```

which means you are defining a function that always returns `True`, but then checking if that *function* has a truthy value, which it does because all `function` objects are truthy.

You want to *call* the function with some argument; for this example, I just created an arbitrary instance of `object`, but the argument can be literally *anything*.

```
if (lambda x: True)(object()) == True
    print('yes')
```

It's easier to see if you break it into multiple lines:

```
f = lambda x: True
some_arg = object()
if f(some_arg) == True:   # or just if f(some_arg):
    print('yes')
```

Comment: *...which it does because it is simply an object.* Not quite. Assumes being an object automatically qualifies it for truthiness, which is not true  (pun intended).

Comment: I should have said `object` (or even more specifically, `function`), rather than object.

Answer (score 1):

You are not **calling** your lambdas. What you're doing here is to test the boolean value of the lambda object itself (actually a `function` object), which is of course always true.

If you want to test the result of the lambda, you have to call it - and in your case you'll have to pass it an argument since you define it has taking an argument:

```
if (lambda x: True)(42):
   print("yes")

if (lambda x: False)(42):
   print("no")
```

Now this don't really make sense in your snippet since Python lambdas are restricted to a single expression so you could as well replace the whole `(lambda x: whatever_expression)(whatever_value)` with `whatever_expression`.

Also as Chepner mentions, your `if` condition is actually parsed as:

```
if (lambda x: True == True):
```

not as:

```
if (lambda x: True) == True:
```

this doesn't make much difference here since as I explained first what gets tested here the boolean value of the lambda `function` object itself, but anyway... As a general rule, explicitely testing against `True` or `False` is useless in python - all objects have a boolean value, and all expressions yield objects, so this

```
if some_expression == True:
```

is the same as

```
if some_expression:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
True_X = lambda x: True
False_X = lambda x: False
Not_X = lambda x: (True if x == False else False)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.